# Can't click on bootstrap dropdown navigation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem regarding bootstrap navigation, on some devices dropdown navigation isn't working, you can't click on it. Client reported it, but i can't cause that problem on my pc. I tried it from several pc but didn't have any luck.Any idea how can i solve it or cause it?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by copying all of the page html into here; if there are any errors, fix those first: http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Second, look at the console in your own browser: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ Are there any errors? If so, fix them.

If those doesn't fix the issue, sign up for a (free) trial subscription to a browser testing server, e.g. crossbrowsertesting If you can't replicate the issue yourself, figuring out the problem will be really difficult. It might be that a browser plugin the user uses is causing the problem, which has nothing to do with your site. Replicating the issue yourself is generally an important first step to fixing the issue. Nobody here can give you a definitive answer to your question as is, because it's too open-ended.

Try to figure out what devices the issue occurs on, then do some googling, search stack overflow etc. for specific problems with those devices and bootstrap nav. If it happens on Android devices and you happen to have one, you can debug on your own device: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/ Start by looking at the console to see if there are any javascript errors.

Comment: No errors in console.. The funny thing is he uses win10 and he has that problem, i've even booted it on my pc to check it and no luck, ironically when he opens it in IE it works fine.. Nor chrome or mozilla works for him. Can it be due to some installed plugins or browser version..

Comment: @Jacky it can definitely be due to installed plugins or browser version. It could be due to his browser caching a very old version of jquery. It could be due to....about a million other things.